# SQL group query to get data from two table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `department` table and `user` table and it is obvious that each associate is in different departments.
I want to get all the users of each department separately. Can I do it by group by or...?

My attempt is as following which does not give me the desired result:

```
select username,b.deptName
  from user a 
 inner join dept b 
    on a.dept=deptId group by deptName
```

PS: I need one SQL query to get associates of different departments not for each department a separate query!

---

**Sample data**

```
User(Table)

username  dept

John       1
Jack       2    
Sam        1
Tedy       1
Tom        2
Sara       2

dept:(Table)
deptId deptName
1      HR
2      IT

My Desired result:
HR:John-Sam-Tedy
IT:Jack-Tom-Sara
```

Comment: pls provide some sample data.Your question is hard to understand?

Comment: can u provide some sample output?

Comment: Are you looking for `Order by` instead of `Group by`?

Comment: Not the clearest question, Shima. Given you want a record for every combination of department and associate, just remove your group by clause. If that's not what you want, you may need to rephrase. Why not give us some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Thanks! I added my sample data!

Answer (score 5):

A single query returns a single resultset, not separate resultsets.

The GROUP BY in your query is going to eliminate lots of rows.

If you want a single row for each department, then you could use the GROUP_CONCAT function, although it is subject to some limitations. (Maximum length is limited by `max_allowed_packet`, and you need to use a delimiter that doesn't appear as a character in any username.

```
SELECT b.deptName
     , GROUP_CONCAT(a.username ORDER BY a.username ASC SEPARATOR '-') AS usernames
  FROM user a
  JOIN dept b
    ON a.dept=b.deptId
 GROUP BY b.deptName
```

I recommend you include some sort of ORDER BY in the GROUP_CONCAT so that result will be deterministic, and not vary from run to run.

A more desirable output would probably be a separate row for each username. You could use an ORDER BY clause to get the rows for a department next to each other. They wouldn't really be "separate", but the rows would be ordered.

```
SELECT b.deptName
     , a.username
  FROM user a
  JOIN dept b
    ON a.dept=b.deptId
 ORDER BY b.deptName, a.username
```

---

**Q:** could you please explain "max_allowed_packet" is the limitation based on the number of characters or the actual size like 1MB,...?

**A:**

The string returned by the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function has a limited length. I believe the limit is specified in bytes (rather than characters), and is derived from the current value of the `max_allowed_packet` session variable.

For example:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

Variable_name       Value    
------------------  ---------
max_allowed_packet  1048576
```

So this means that the string returned by GROUP_CONCAT can be more than 1MB.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your first solution seems what I have been looking for! But could you please explain "max_allowed_packet" is the limitation based on the number of characters or the actual size like 1MB,...? because if the limitation is based on the actual size that's fine for my case but the number of characters I 'm not sure

Comment: I loved your answer, but it seems the usernames column in your example exceeds the limitation and it does not show all of the usernames in my database :( I tried to increase the limitation but no success!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `STUFF` for your result.
try this

```
SELECT D.department,
    STUFF((
    SELECT '-'+ U1.userName
    FROM user U1 inner join department D1 ON U1.dept_ID=D1.dept_ID
    WHERE D1.deptName= D.deptName
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    ,1,0,'') AS users
FROM user U inner join department D ON U.dept_ID=D.dept_ID
GROUP BY D.deptName
```